# Electromagnetic physiology

Tags: xenobiology, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

An electromagnetic ray fired from the my organism mouth, the EM Beam is incredibly deadly to those on the receiving end as the beam’s magnetism is up to 1 quadrillion gauss and strong enough to disrupt covalent bonds of molecules. Powerful to dissolve the molecular structure of any matter. What process take place in this process of creating this beam ?

Comment: Welcome Balamurugan. Could you clarify what the actual question is? Please also take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways. Enjoy worldbuilding. One thing you might make clear, how the creature itself survives (or anything within thousands of Km, come to that) with neutron-star breath.

Comment: For reference, a magnetar might have a magnetic field of 1 trillion gauss: see https://www.space.com/30263-paul-sutter-on-why-magnetars-are-scary.html. This is 1,000 times stronger, and the creature shooting it will kill itself the second it hits even a thousandth of that strength. From my personal perspective, it just seems like you found a big number and decided that that's how powerful this thing was.

Comment: Please that also my question how this organism generates this and protect itself from its own incredible em beam

Comment: It can't, it's not possible as far as we understand physics. Please ask a single question per post, it's what we do here.

Comment: That kind of magnetic field would dissolve any non-degenerate matter within several kilometres.  Also, you're not going to get a 'beam', it'll be a field.  So, unless we're talking about an entirely different universe with rules we just don't have any way of understanding, this just isn't going to happen.

Comment: If you're asking about a creature that lives in a universe with the same laws that we have, then the correct answer is probably "that is not possible". If it lives in a universe with different laws that allow this phenomenon then please edit your question to illustrate those details.

Comment: Yes think it is a boron based lifeform

Comment: Your accounts keep getting system blocked because you keep asking low quality question. Deleting the accounts and creating new ones won't solve the issue, until you learn how to ask good questions.

Comment: VTC:NAW The [help/on-topic] states that questions "Must be specific and answerable" and the [help/dont-ask] further states, "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." Asking us to invent the biology of the creature you describe violates both rules. You also [might want to do some research into magnetic fields](https://www.wtamu.edu/~cbaird/sq/2014/08/21/what-is-the-strongest-magnetic-field-possible-is-there-a-limit/), what you're suggesting would rip apart solar systems.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that, in order to protect itself, your creature would have to cover the surface area of its skin (as well as surface area of the interior of its mouth and of the interiors of all the other components of its digestive and respiratory systems) with portals that were capable of teleporting the extinction-event-level quantity of magnetic fields into deep space, or another dimension, or some other location of a similar distance.  If you want, you could even say that these types of portals only teleport magnetic fields and don't register on the visible light spectrum, making it so that your creature simply appears to be immune to the effects of his blast that could wipe out all other physical life on a planet.